# Disable permanently or uninstall the exchange services

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, exchange, services

I'm fighting with the exchange services on my Samsung Galaxy S4. They can render the phone unusable, draining even 40-50% of battery during the day. I've deactivated the Exchange account mail synchronization, and I'm constatly killing the app when I notice it's running, but it keeps respawning which is extremally annoying. And if I don't notice, I can find myself out outside without battery power to do other things I need.

Is there a way to permanently disable the exchange services, or even completely remove it from the device?

Answer (score 2):

First try clearing the app data of the stock email app in settings->apps, if that doesn't work:
If you go to settings->apps again and click on the stock email app (not gmail) then click disable, that should do the trick. 
However:
If you still have a non-gmail email you could try lowering the sync frequency from push to every 30 mins.

Comment: That trick didn't work. The option to turn notifications off is disabled. The app is closed now, but I'm afraid, it will start in the worst moment.

Comment: What about the option to disable?

Comment: I don't see such an option. But I don't see the appplication 'Stock Email' either. I've checked 'Exchange Services'.

Comment: Sorry, by stock I meant default, the app is just called email

Comment: OK. The option to turn off is currently disabled. I will observe it.

Comment: Try force stopping and then the option should become enabled

Answer (score 1):

You need to root your phone to permanently uninstall it.

After you have rooted your device, you can use a application "Titanium Backup" to uninstall those useless application that come along with the phone.

Advice: make a copy of backup first. In case you find that you need the application after you uninstall it.

[image: Titanium backup]

<sup>Click image for larger version</sup>

Comment: Unfortunatelly rooting that phone is out of question because it's not my phone, but it's good to know for the future, althought I doubt I'd ever buy Samsung Galaxy.

Comment: @Donaudampfschifffreizeitfahrt These are the kind of things recommended to specify in the question :)

Answer (score 0):

you might try clearing the caches from recovery. that seems to help slow down for me.

1. power down the device
2. press and hold vol up + home + power until you enter recovery mode.
3. press vol down until "wipe cache partition" is highlighted, then press power to select.
4. let recovery wipe and format the cache partition.
5. then select "reboot system now" to boot back into android.

hopefully that helps. exchange services handles account data for google, facebook, etc. removing or disabling it can cause system instability.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how much Samsung has diverged from stock Android, but on my Android 5.1 device, I can disable Exchange Services by going to Settings → Apps → All tab → Exchange Services → Disable.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered this thread just today and want to say that:

Whenever Exchange or EAS/Activesync causes the battery drain, it seems to be the notes and tasks that are causing the problem.  It happened with stock exchange app when Tasks was synced,  and also happened with "Nine - Exchange for Android" when Notes was synced.

Also, Google version of exchange email, downloadable from APK downloading websites, does the same with Tasks synced.

None of the apps had battery issue when only Email, Calendar, and Contacts were synced.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the "Application manager",
Select the "Change system settings"(three spots at the right top corner) in there,
Select "Show System Apps"(three spots at the right top corner) in there,
Find the "Exchange services" on the lists and set the mode to OFF

Answer (score -1):

Sure. It's super easy and worth freezing that app. Open App Info and tap on "Disable".

Comment: Where would this "App Info" be? How do I access it to disable the app, if not uninstall it?

Answer (score -1):

Go to settings, apps, open exchange services, uninstall